# First two Months Blank and then calculate average

Tags: excel

I have three columns "Month Name" "Team" and "Mismatch%
I have 8 months of data for each and I am trying to calculate 3 months rolling average as shown in the below table.

Every time the team changes the first two months should be blank as shown in the image. Currently I have data from Fiscal Month June to January hence June and July should be blank. If i have data from Fiscal month July to Feb then July and August will be blank and so on.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsIxQ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcBC3.png)

I tried my luck using Offset and average function in excel. But did not get the desired results. If anyone could help me to write a condition or formula to keep first two months cell blank and then calculate average will be very helpful.

Awaiting your positive response!

Thanks,
G

Comment: When asking a question, try to writte what you want. `I tried my luck using Offset and average function in excel. But did not get the desired results` doesnt help as we cannot understand what you want/need.  Is replacing blank with zero/null values enough for you?

Comment: I am sorry Bonnati, Will keep your suggestion in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this in cell D4 and copy down:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B$2:B4,B4)<=2,"",AVERAGE(C2:C4))
```

[image]